# Why am I getting RemoteServiceException when creating a notification on some devices?

Tags: android, android-notifications

When my app creates a notification, its main activity disappears without a trace. This could just be a regular uncaught exception, because I'm not sure this particular device would show an error message in that case.

This problem only occurs on a Huawei Y560-L01 running Android 5.1.1. I don't have access to the device myself, which makes it tricky to debug. I could not reproduce it on an emulator configured with similar specs and running Lollipop (5.1).

Here's how I create the notification:

```
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

private final PlaybackService service; // Inherits from Service
private Bitmap logoBitmap; // Initialized before the notification is created

private void someMethod() {
    ...
    service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
    ...
}

private Notification createNotification() {
    PendingIntent contentIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(service)
        .addParentStack(MainActivity.class)
        .addNextIntent(new Intent(service, MainActivity.class))
        .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    PendingIntent stopIntent = service.createPendingIntentForAction(PlaybackService.STOP_ACTION);
    PendingIntent pauseIntent = service.createPendingIntentForAction(PlaybackService.PAUSE_ACTION);
    PendingIntent playIntent = service.createPendingIntentForAction(PlaybackService.PLAY_ACTION);

    NotificationCompat.MediaStyle mediaStyle = new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0 /* Play/Pause */, 1 /* Stop */)
        .setShowCancelButton(true)
        .setCancelButtonIntent(stopIntent);

    int smallIcon = player.getState() == PlayerState.PLAYING ? R.drawable.ic_status_bar_play : R.drawable.ic_status_bar_pause;
    Bitmap largeIcon = logoBitmap;

    NotificationCompat.Action playOrPauseAction;
    if (player.getState() == PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        playOrPauseAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause", pauseIntent);
    } else {
        playOrPauseAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_play, "Play", playIntent);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Action stopAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_stop, "Stop", stopIntent);

    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(service.getApplicationContext())
        .setContentTitle(player.getStation().getName())
        .setContentText(player.getCurrentTrack())
        .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
        .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .addAction(playOrPauseAction)
        .addAction(stopAction)
        .setStyle(mediaStyle)
        .build();
}
```

This is the `RemoteServiceException` that results in the app's death:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(14550): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(14550): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14550): Process: com.frozenfractal.radio, PID: 14550
E/AndroidRuntime(14550): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.frozenfractal.radio: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.frozenfractal.radio user=UserHandle{0} id=1 tag=null score=-10 key=0|com.frozenfractal.radio|1|null|10174: Notification(pri=-1 contentView=com.frozenfractal.radio/0x109007f vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 category=service actions=2 vis=PUBLIC))
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1480)
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
E/AndroidRuntime(14550):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
I/Process (14550): Sending signal. PID: 14550 SIG: 9
```

However, this is preceded by an error in `StatusBar` (a different process), of type `android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException`, which I think might be more relevant:

```
E/StatusBar( 3283): couldn't inflate view for notification com.frozenfractal.radio/0x1
E/StatusBar( 3283): android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: view: android.view.ViewStub doesn't have method: setTextColor(int)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.getMethod(RemoteViews.java:776)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.access$300(RemoteViews.java:75)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.widget.RemoteViews$ReflectionAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1285)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2677)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2637)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.inflateViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1201)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.createNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:1415)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.addNotification(PhoneStatusBar.java:1660)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$4$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:300)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
E/StatusBar( 3283):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
I/StatusBar( 3283): pkg com.frozenfractal.radio block 6
W/StatusBar( 3283): removeNotification for unknown key: 0|com.frozenfractal.radio|1|null|10174
D/PhoneStatusBar( 3283): mNotificationData.hasActiveClearableNotifications()=false
D/NotificationService(  953): onNotification error pkg=com.frozenfractal.radio tag=null id=1; will crashApplication(uid=10174, pid=14550)
```

It's true that `ViewStub` doesn't have a `setTextColor(int)` method, so I'm guessing there should not have been a `ViewStub` here, but rather an (inflated) `TextView` or similar.

I dived into the Android sources a bit, but it wasn't really enlightening. The `RemoteViews$ActionException` is thrown [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/RemoteViews.java?av=f#771). This is caught and logged by `BaseStatusBar` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java?av=f#1411).

Possibly relevant lines from `build.gradle` (I know some of this is out of date, but upgrading gave me a slew of compilation errors that I don't have time for right now):

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 24
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}
```

There are a lot of questions on StackOverflow which ask about the `RemoteServiceException`, but most don't show any output from the `StatusBar` process, so it's hard to say if they're the same. And most are unanswered anyway. Only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335277/android-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-package-couldnt-ca) seems to have a possible workaround in the comments. I also found [this bug report](https://github.com/AntennaPod/AntennaPod/issues/959) for a different app, which shows the same stack traces, and is also on a Huawei device. It apparently got fixed by a system update, so it might not entirely be my own fault for a change.

If I had access to the device, I would try to simplify the notification until the problem goes away, but unfortunately I don't have that luxury. Does anyone see anything (potentially) wrong with my code? Or have an idea how I could change the code to reproduce the issue on an emulator?

Comment: "Does anyone see anything (potentially) wrong with my code?" -- it seems OK. This issue [was reported previously](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37078372), if I am interpreting that issue and your question correctly. Huawei probably tinkered with something that the support library developers did not expect.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that looks quite relevant, thanks for digging it up! I was also looking at [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36946453) which might somehow be related as well. I can imagine the support library implementing the `MediaStyle` as a custom remote view, and if the custom view is ignored then views that should have `setTextColor` might not have it...